# How to redirect to index page when no internet connectivity is detected in webview

Tags: android

I am creating a web android app, I want a situation whereby I don't want the user to notice the default browser error message when there is no internet. I have already created an activity which does that but when I click on a link when there is no internet it show the default browser message.

here is my network activity

```
package com.example.infonet.greenparrotnews;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Nointernet extends AppCompatActivity {

    private boolean isConnected = false;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "CheckNetworkStatus";
    private NetworkChangeReceiver receiver;
    private TextView networkStatus;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nointernet);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        receiver = new NetworkChangeReceiver();
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        networkStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.networkStatus);
    }






    public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Receieved notification about network status");
            isNetworkAvailable(context);

        }


        private boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
            ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if (connectivity != null) {
                NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
                if (info != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                        if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                            if(!isConnected){
                                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Now you are connected to Internet!");
                                networkStatus.setText("Now you are connected to Internet!");
                                isConnected = true;
                                //Intent q2 = new Intent(Nointernet.this, MainActivity.class);
                                //startActivity(q2);
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "You are not connected to Internet!");
            networkStatus.setText("You are not connected to Internet!");
            isConnected = false;
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
private void cache() {
    webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT); // load online by default
    if (!isNetworkAvailable()) { // loading offline
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    }
}

/** Checks for an active network connection: */
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```